# c++ error compiling when trying to unlink files

Tags: c++, unlink

I'm using this code I found on stackoverflow.. this seems to work well for my requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {

    std::map< std::string, std::string > MyMap;
    std::map< std::string, std::string >::iterator MyIterMap; 

       MyMap["Teste1"] = "map1";
       MyMap["Teste2"] = "map2";
       MyMap["Teste3"] = "map3";

   MyIterMap = MyMap.begin(); 

   while(MyIterMap != MyMap.end() ) {
       std::string key = (*MyIterMap).first; 

       std::cout << "Key: " << key << ", Value: " << MyMap[key] <<std::endl;
       MyIterMap++;
   }
   _getch();
   return 0;

}
```

After each loop, before `MyInterMap++` I'm trying to unlink a file based on the value of `key` as the filename. eg:

`unlink ("/tmp/" + key);`

When I try and complie I get:

```
In function ‘int main()’:

error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int unlink(const char*)’
```

Please can some one advise how I do this ?

Thank you for you time.

Comment: Sorry I've sorted this.. I realised what I'd done as I read this back..

Comment: This resolved it: `unlink( ("/tmp/" + key).c_str() ) ;`

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself, for the benefit of future humans!

Comment: Post it as the answer. It will help other people with the same problem.

Comment: It's probably not a problem in this case, but I would be careful of passing pointers to (the internals of) temporaries to functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer to a C string to the unlink function:

```
const std::string filename = "/tmp/" + key;
unlink(filename.c_str());
```

It's probably not a problem in this case as `unlink` is unlikely to store the C string pointer anywhere, but do note that the pointer becomes dangling as soon as the variable `filename` goes out of scope. If you pass a pointer to a C string obtained from a `std::string` anywhere, make sure that that pointer does not get used after the `std::string` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it by using

`unlink( ("/tmp/" + key).c_str() ) ;`

Thanks